# Wiki-like "create this page" with page manager?

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

I want to make it easier for editors to create new pages with page manager.  Is there a way to provide a "create this page" functionality for non-existent paths, so that editors can insert a new path in existing pages and proceed to create and edit the new page, just like editing a wiki?

I am wondering if I can implement this feature by using a menu tab like [this](http://nodeone.se/da/node/699) to redirect unhandled path to the page manager's creating page.  Helps are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should achieve that by using the following extensions:

- [wikitools](http://drupal.org/project/wikitools)
- [freelinking](http://drupal.org/project/freelinking)

You should have a look at this screencast:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHsjjHzYOSg

It is done with Drupal 7, however, wikitools is still in alpha for Drupal 7.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to add the 2 links for the extensions.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal answers. The links have been added.